# What's the name of the greater than indicator after the sender name in the iOS Mail app?

Tags: ios, component

is there a name for the small "greater than" sign used as indicator in Apple Mail on iOS?

[image: Indicator looking like a greater than sign]

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Chevron right

> Many software programs use *chevron* markings to expand a menu or view other options that may not currently be visible *[Computerhope](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/chevron.htm)*

[image]

<sub>*[Fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons/chevron-right?s=solid&f=classic)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much :)